# Getting error message in Paypal integration

Tags: html, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate Paypal but after clicking on the button it's asking for buyer login details and I entered the correct details then after the process it's showing below error.
I don't know whats working with code. I am integrating first time on my site. Would you help me?

**HTML**

```
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="code"><!--id which comes from after creating a buy button-->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail-facilitator@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Widget">
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it mandatory to create a business account or can we use with the help of individual account? I am using the individual account.

Comment: Please share the reason for down vote. So that I can improve in the future

Answer (score 0):

The email address needs to be created in the PayPal Sandbox Environment. Go to https://developer.paypal.com and login to the Dashboard. Under the Sandbox, go to Accounts and select the email address listed under Type-Business. You may need to reset your password, choose the Profile link.

Use this email address to login to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/buttons/, create your button here, once you save changes, you'll be given the HTML code for testing.

Comment: Thanks for reply @PP_MSI_Lehi, I already created Sandbox account and button, This error I am getting after entered the buyer user details when buying the product.